# Query 2 values from a column of one table and join to another table?

Tags: postgresql

I currently query two tables in a view used by others. I have tried a few different ways on building the query, but the best time I am getting is between 10 and 15 minutes to return values. The query is:

```
SELECT a.unit_location_id, a.location_name, a.serial_number, a.unit_name,
a.rating, b.max_number, c.min_number

FROM details a

JOIN (SELECT serial_number, setting_value AS max_number
FROM settings WHERE setting_name = 'max number') b ON a.serial_number = b.serial_number

JOIN (SELECT serial_number, setting_value AS min_number
FROM settings WHERE setting_name = 'min number') c ON a.serial_number = c.serial_number

WHERE b.max = c.min;
```

Any ideas to that could speed up the query, or what am I missing?

Comment: can you provide any statistics, explain analyze, table structures , indexes you have on table?

Comment: I am working to get statistical information that I can share  The tables are in 2 different schemes. They are not index the same and serial_number is an index of the newer table, but not of the older table. These are large tables, details table has 30+ columns. Settings is using a newer database design, less columns but hundreds of records for each serial_number.  detail queries return in seconds (less than 20), settings is a little slower(about 1 minute).  It's just when I join the tables looking for errors (max = min) that the time goes up above 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using "WITH" the time goes from 10 to 15 minutes to less than a minute. Most times in under 30 seconds.

```
WITH settings AS (
     SELECT serial_number, 
            CASE WHEN setting_name = 'max number' THEN setting_value END AS max_number,
            CASE WHEN setting_name = 'min number' THEN setting_value END AS min_number
     FROM settings
     WHERE setting_name IN ('max number', 'min number'))

SELECT a.unit_location_id, a.location_name, a.serial_number, a.unit_name,
       a.rating, b.setting_value AS min_number, c.setting_value AS max_number 
FROM details a
LEFT JOIN settings b ON a.serial_number = b.serial_number 
         AND max_number IS NOT NULL
LEFT JOIN settings c ON a.serial_number = c.serial_number 
         AND max_number IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, if you could eliminate one of those two joins, that might give you an immediate noticeable improvement in performance.  Appreciate that we can actually identify the max and min numbers, for each serial number, in the `settings` table by using a single aggregation query.  In the query below, I join `details` to a single subquery which finds the max and min numbers.

```
SELECT
    a.unit_location_id,
    a.location_name,
    a.serial_number,
    a.unit_name,
    a.rating,
    t.max_number,
    t.min_number
FROM details a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        serial_number,
        MAX(CASE WHEN setting_name = 'max number' THEN setting_value END) AS max_number,
        MAX(CASE WHEN setting_name = 'min number' THEN setting_value END) AS min_number
    FROM settings
    GROUP BY serial_number
) t
    ON a.serial_number = t.serial_number
WHERE
    t.max_number = t.min_number;
```

Comment: I didn't think about the CASE WHEN, thanks help some but the setting table my just be to large.